# How can I upload my animated GIFs to Facebook (in 2015)

Tags: facebook, images, feeds, upload, status

According to [this Mashable article](http://mashable.com/2015/05/29/facebook-gif-support/#XV0YwIWlaOq1), Facebook only recently started supporting GIF support.

From the article, here's how it works: "*you need to paste a GIF file link into the "status update" screen*"

Also "*make sure you're using the full GIF url from Giphy or other GIF services*".

So, all this is all right for the situations in which you want to share a GIF that's already hosted on a GIF hosting website such as [GIPHY](http://giphy.com/), [Imgur](http://imgur.com/), [GFYcat](https://gfycat.com/) and others: you copy the link, and paste it, and voilà.

But if you're the original author of the GIF and want to share something not hosted? "No GIF uploads" says the article.

So I hosted my test GIF file on my own website at this address:
http://fabulousrice.com/images/uploads/works/hairy.gif

Then pasted the address in the "Status Update" field, and clicked "Post".

The result didn't work, in the way that not only the GIF turned into a still image on my Facebook Feed, but the GIF file also couldn't even be played from Facebook, only after being redirected to the the original URL:

[image]

*(this is just a screenshot, but wasn't animated IRL)*

Note how there isn't even a "GIF" button in the middle to play it, such as the one seen here on the Mashable article:

[image]

I tried with another URL that ends also in GIF, but from GIPHY this time:
http://i.giphy.com/3o6UBpHgaXFDNAuttm.gif

And this time it worked!

[image]

*(this is just a screenshot but **was** animated IRL).*

In both of my examples, I used the same approach by pasting a GIF file's URL to the Status Update box on Facebook. But only one of them worked.

What makes the two URLs ending in .GIF different in the eyes of Facebook?

And how can I upload my work to Facebook as animated GIFs that play within the Feed, if I don't feel like uploading my GIFs to GIPHY, or Imgurl, or any other of these websites?

I have seen other questions on that subject here, but they were from 2010-2011, and I believe that they are now obsolete.

Comment: Can you try to post your gif image on GYPHY/Imgur and see if it's working?

Comment: I think there is a problem with your file, because I uploaded it to GYPHY and it doesn’t show as GIF on Facebook.

Comment: I suspect that Facebook has white-listed a limited number of sites from which they'll accept animated GIFs.

Comment: There are quite possibly restrictions on the GIF. ie. Physical size, file size, number of frames, duration, etc. [This thread](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10155738328590150) mentions that it should be no wider than the news feed and under 89 frames. The mashable article also mentions that GIFs are only supported on personal feeds, not _pages_ (although that would not seem to be the problem here).

Comment: > how can I upload my work to Facebook as animated GIFs that play within the Feed, if I don't feel like uploading my GIFs to GIPHY, or Imgurl, or any other of these websites You cannot. That's the point. It's a whitelisted feature for select Facebook partners. If any and everybody could do it, Facebook feeds would be cluttered with garbage.

Comment: Are you saying GIPHY et al. Isn't garbage?